# JQuery nested each loops with ajax calls and promises?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Context - My page dynamically loads a lot of div containers within which there are either 1 or 2 images loaded but hidden. Once all hidden images are loaded (I'm using the waitForImages JQuery plugin to ensure this) I loop through each container and through each image in each container and send an ajax call off to a php function which determines the dominant colour pixel within that image. When this ajax call returns the colour or colours (if there are two images) the script sets the container to that colour/those colours.

I've got it working perfectly if I force the ajax call to work synchronously but this freezes my page when there's a lot of images to go through, as you can imagine. I could really do with it loading the containers and then allowing interaction on the page while it updates the container colours in the background.

Here is an example of one of the containers, after the process is complete (with background colours therefore applied):

```
<div class="image_product" style="background-color: rgb(186, 214, 78);" onclick="view_product(27);">
    <img style="display:none;" src="/module_uploads/image_replacer/23/110914130755_0_94.jpg">
    <img style="display:none;" src="/module_uploads/image_replacer/13/180614104219_0_94.jpg">
    <div class="product_grid_heart_container" style="border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important; background-color: rgb(239, 63, 63);">
        <div class="product_grid_heart"> AK/H </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my code that makes that happen, by synchronously:

```
$('div.image_product').each(function() {
    var colors = [];
    $(this).find('img').each(function() {
        var img = $(this).attr('src');
        var sanitised_img1 = img.replace(/\//, "");
        var sanitised_img = sanitised_img1.replace(/\//g, "***");
        $.ajax({
             async: false,
             type: "POST",
             url: '/general/dominant_colour/'+sanitised_img+'/rgb',
             success: function(dominant_colour) {
                colors.push(dominant_colour);
             }
        });
    });
    if($(this).find('.secondary_cat_image').length > 0)
    {
        $(this).find('.product_grid_heart_container').css({"background-color": "rgb(" + colors[0] + ")"});
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(" + colors[0] + ")");
        if(colors.length > 1)
        {
            $(this).find('.product_grid_heart_container').css({"background-color": "rgb(" + colors[1] + ")"});
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).find('.product_grid_heart_container').css({"background-color": "rgb(" + colors[0] + ")", "border-top-color": "rgb(" + colors[0] + ")"});
        }
    }
});
```

Like I said this works perfectly as is, it just freezes the page which I cannot have. I'm sure the answer lies in promises but while the examples I've found make sense I really struggle with applying them to my situation and I end up totally baffled. Any help appreciated greatly!

Comment: what do you mean with *promises* ?

Comment: You're performing all the actions on the `div.image_product` element (as far as I can tell. So, a `$('div.image_product').promise(function() { // your code here });` should be what you are looking for.

Comment: @DevlshOne could you give me an example of how you would do this/where this would go in relation the each loops?

Comment: @HelenDangerBurns If you'll create a JSFiddle to represent your scenario, I'd be glad to mark it up for you.